# Object is instanceof two disjoint classes

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I built a Wildfly application using javax validations to validate incoming models.
Now I am trying to write an Exception mapper that catches any ValidationException.

```
@Provider
public class MyValidationMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ValidationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ValidationException exception) {

        if (exception instanceof ResteasyViolationException) {
            // do something specific
        }

        if (exception instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
            // do something specific
        }

        // do something generic
    }
}
```

As you can see I want special treatment for `ResteasyViolationException` and `ConstraintViolationException`, both of which are direct subclasses of `ValidationException`.

The problem is that `exception` is an instance of **both** of these types.

```
System.out.println(exception instanceof ResteasyViolationException);
System.out.println(exception instanceof ConstraintViolationException);
```

yields `true` each time.
Hence the behaviour of my mapper depends on the order in which I check the exception's type.

How is that possible? Apparently my understanding of `instanceof` has some gaps. Or is there anything special about Resteasy?

Comment: Obviously the types aren't disjoint. Check for the more specific one first (and probably use an `else if`).

Comment: Both if blocks have a return statement, so `else if` would not make a difference. @Kayaman s hint was helpful though, I might beusing a different library on the server than I thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [javadoc](https://access.redhat.com/webassets/avalon/d/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/7.0.0/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/api/validation/package-tree.html), `org.jboss.resteasy.api.validation.ResteasyViolationException` extends `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException`, so when handling the latter you'll always be handling the former as well.

An option is to not use `instanceof`, but check with `getClass()` for the actual type. However beware of any classloader related weirdnesses.

Comment: just adding that in this case an `else if` instead of a simple `if` could really help.

Comment: You're right of course, as long as the order is correct.

Comment: I am using `resteasy-validator-provider-11`. According to [their docs](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.18.Final/javadocs/index.html) it is a direct subclass of `ValidationException`. Ok I need to investigate what library is actually used. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem is that you are taking the wrong conclusions from your observations.

Your observation told you: those two exceptions can't be "disjoint".
So the most meaningful response would be to question your own **assumption** that those two are disjoint; for example by studying javadocs. Which would have told you what Kayamann told you in his answer: those two classes are in fact related to each other.

Meaning: don't assume that a language that does single-inheritance for 20+ years ... all of a sudden "breaks" with that, just because you run into something that seems to contradict this concept.

In other words: always ask yourself first "why do I assume that this or that must be like that" when reality contradicts your expectations.

Comment: Hence my question "How can that be?". I was not suggesting that Java introduced multi inheritance but asking what I am missing. The answer was that I checked the docs of the wrong lib.